# onclick change background of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with a div changing background but i also need it to change back when the background color has been applied.

Code: JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() { 
    if (document.getElementById("demo").style.background == "#ff77ee") {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "#000";
} else{
    document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "#ff77ee";
}
}
```

Code: HTML:

```
<div id="demo" onclick="javascript:myFunction();"></div>
```

Code: Style: ( Its in my Index File )

```
#demo{
    background: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**What i would like it to do is that i want to onclick change the background color to pink. then if i click on it again i would like the color to be the original color - Black.**

Comment: check `backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function myFunction() { 
    var e = document.getElementById("demo");
    var c = window.getComputedStyle(e).backgroundColor;
    if (c === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "#ff77ee";
} else{
    document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "#000";
}
}
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ovaqqgrr/1/)

Comment: Glad this helps you out. :) Enjoy scripting.

Comment: Always lovely when guys with information helps out. Thanks alot again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("demo").style.background) {//<-- already having bg
    document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "";//<-- remove it
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "#ff77ee";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" onclick="javascript:myFunction();">hi</div>
```

**EDIT**

```js
var div = document.getElementById('demo');

var myFunction = function() {
  var clas = div.className.split(' ');
  var i;
  if (-1 === (i = clas.indexOf('bg'))) {
    clas.push('bg');
  } else {
    clas.splice(i, 1);
  }
  div.className = clas.join(" ");
};

myFunction(); //just for testing
```

```css
.bg {
  background: pink !important;
}
.brd {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.pad {
  padding: 5px 7px;
}
.bg2 {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" onclick="myFunction();" class='brd pad bg2'>hi there</div>
```

Comment: The thing that i would like it to do after i changed the background color is to change it back to the base color - Black. The box works fine if i press on it. but when i try and function it back to black with an if statement it just wont.

Comment: @Frederik, I would suggest using css class, have a look at my updated post

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("demo").style.background
```

This line return an rgb color, like :

```
"rgb(255, 119, 238)"
```

So you can use :

```
function myFunction() { 
    if (document.getElementById("header").style.background == "rgb(255, 119, 238)") {
        document.getElementById("header").style.background = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
    } else{
        document.getElementById("header").style.background = "rgb(255, 119, 238)";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here your solution. I use a boolean variable and less code.

```js
var bool = true;
function myFunction() { 
 
    (bool) ? document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "#ff77ee" :  document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "black";
    bool = !bool;

}
```

```css
#demo{
    background: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" onclick="javascript:myFunction();"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#demo").click(function(){

   $("#demo").css('background','red');   

});

});



<div id="demo"> test </div>
```

You can do it simply  by jquery need to add jquery file   latest

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It is `backgroundColor` in Javascript
2. It is `background-color` in CSS
3. You need to get computed style for applied styles

***Snippet:***

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("demo");
var c = window.getComputedStyle(elem).backgroundColor;
alert(c);
```

```css
#demo{
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" ></div>
```